# IBM x3690 x5 Light Path Diagnostic Circle of Death Mainboard Failure?

Tags: hardware, ibm, ibm-xseries

I have serious trouble with a x3690. After moving it to a new server rack it won't startup.

After connecting the server to power supply the Light Path Diagnostic LEDs turn wheels. The normal behaviour would be that the power button blinks fast (4 times per second) and then goes into a slow blink, when you can start it.

I double checked every loose part (cables) and also checked RAM and powersupplies and power bridge.

I also tried to remove CMOS battery, as well as setting the jumpers to reset CMOS

I think that it is probaly the mainboard which is defect? Any ideas ?

Comment: IBM support would be my first stop.

Comment: sadly it is an old machine - support discontinoued

Comment: Check [all the LEDs on the panel](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systemx/documentation/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sysx.7944.doc/r_light_path_diagnostics_table.html) as well as [all the LEDs on the system board](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systemx/documentation/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sysx.7944.doc/r_light_path_diagnostics_table.html).

Comment: Thx for the LED idea, i checked all LEDs only mainboard battery run out everything else is ok from LED perspective, so i still think the mainboard is broken. I ordered a sparepart.